# Symfony HTTP header Authorization tag returns NULL

Tags: php, symfony, http, http-headers, authorization

I am experimenting with the Symfony 2.8 `AbstractGuardAuthenticator` to create a simple [Authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html) that takes either a token or a `Base64` encoded username:password. The concept is simple enough but the Authorization tag always returns `NULL` for reasons I don't understand.

HTTP header sent via Postman:

```
POST /testproject/www/app_dev.php/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Authorization: Basic dGVzdDoxMjM0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 30a64d1b-e4e2-4d01-34f3-5e09b90379b6
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----    WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Simple checking code:

```
class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator

public function getCredentials(Request $request) {

        var_dump(base64_decode('dGVzdDoxMjM0'));
        die(var_dump($request->request->get('Authorization')));
}
```

Output:

```
string(9) "test:1234"
NULL
```

Am I calling the right part of request here to get something from the header bag? I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

When I dump the headers I can see the tag which is really frustrating:

```
var_dump($request->headers);

    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag)#15 (2) {
      ["headers":protected]=>
      array(15) {
//other variables cut out because of length
        ["authorization"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(18) "Basic dGVzdDoxMjM0"
        }
    }
```

SOLUTION BY [qooplmao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791606/qooplmao)

Access the headerbag instead of the request via:

```
$request->headers->get('authorization');
```

Comment: Use `$request->headers->get('authorization')` in your `getCredentials` method rather than `$request->request...`.

Comment: @qooplmao well that makes an awful lot of sense now. I did something similar earlier but it told me not to use the headerbag as an array, woops.

Comment: Yeah, my bad for not reading the whole question first time.